# How to change language with short cut?

Tags: 14.04, input-language

I am wondering how I can change the input language with a shortcut key. I'm assuming I will have to create a custom short cut. What will the command be?

Any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pre-defined shortcut for switching input language in Ubuntu: <Super>+<Space>, which you can change if you like. Please see [the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html).